# memset and sprintf equivalent in Node.JS

Tags: javascript, c, node.js

I am trying to port this code to node.JS

```
void init(int a, int b, int internalRounds)
{
    memset(nkey, 0x00, 256);
    sprintf((char*)nkey, "%.5d_XXXXX%.5d_MASIN_%.5d", (a+10), (b+10), (a+b));
    setup(nkey, 256);
    ucPrev = getRandom();
}
```

I want to know how to do this properly.

I currently have:

```
var Crypt = function(a, b, internalRounds) {
  var nkey = new Buffer(256)
  nkey.fill(0x00)

  nkey = util.format('%.5d_XXXXX%.5d_MASIN_%.5d', (a+10), (b+10), (a+b))

  this.setup(nkey, 256)
  this.ucPrev = this.getRandom()
}
```

I would like to understand if I did this correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`util.format` doesn’t support precision (i.e. `%.5f`). In addition, assigning to `nkey` is just replacing your buffer with the string returned from `util.format`. You want to `write` the string to the buffer instead.

Here’s how you might fix those issues:

```
var key = new Buffer(256);
key.fill(0);
key.write(
  (a + 10).toFixed(5) +
  '_XXXXX' +
  (b + 10).toFixed(5) +
  '_MASIN_' +
  (a + b).toFixed(5)
);
```